# Observability for Kalman Filtering?

Tags: kalman-filters

I wanted to know how observability of a stochastic state space system affects the performance of a Kalman Filter. Do we check for the usual observability matrix involving $\mathbf{C}$ (observation matrix) and $\mathbf{A}$ (state transition matrix) or there is a newer notion of stochastic observability? In case of non-observability, does the error between true and estimated states go out of bound ?

Comment: it's one of the few things i remember about the Kalman filter from grad school.  the notion of observability for the KF is precisely the same notion of observability from state-variable control system theory.  (it's the $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ matrix thing.)  and, the result of the KF are estimates of the **states** of the state-variable system.  not directly an estimate of the signal, which you can get with the estimate of the states and the $\mathbf{C}$ matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only quick reference [I can find is this one](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.30.2399&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which states:

[image]

Comment: The link to the quick reference is timing out for me (not a 404, but no response). Any chance you can fix it?

Comment: @Reb.Cabin : The link still opens directly for me. I've made a copy of it on my private Dropbox. [Please try this link.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16631687/10.1.1.30.2399.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

My answer refers to your first question whether it matters to use the usual observability matrix to test for observability in a system with noise.
According to [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ea5e/84449d805454d9ff952e2d3ffc622cb6062e.pdf) it matters. Their justification is the following:

> 1) The "usual" tests for observability do not incorporate the noise
>   covariance matrices, $Q_k$, $R_k$ or $P_0$.
>
> 2) Regardless of
>   whether the $A$ and $C$ matrices satisfy the observability condition, $Q_k$, $R_k$,
>   or $P_0$ could cause the state covariance matrix to become unbounded or exceed a predefined threshold value.

With respect to the above, they propose a stochastic observability test for which you can find more details about it, in the paper above.